# Multi Threading Issue - Need Event after thread completes

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm designing a multi-threaded process where I create a thread to do some processing so as to not lock the UI.  However, when this thread completes (if it completes succesfully w/o error) I need an event so I can execute a method on the UI thread that will update the UI properly.

How can I accomplish this correctly?

My simple code for the Thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetAppUpdates));
t.Start();
```

Now I need to know when the thread completes, but I feel that I don't want to implement code that would constantly check the Thread State because it would cause UI delay.

(I know this is easier with backgroundworker but I don't want a backgroundworker for this process because this Thread cannot be background).

Is there a way to trigger events for Thread objects when they complete?  What is the best way to accomplish a ThreadFinished() event? I have code that must be executed on the Main UI after Thread successful completion.

Comment: Why do you need it to not be a background thread if you've got a UI up? That would stop the process from terminating... anyway, I'd suggest using `Task` rather than `BackgroundWorker`...

Comment: The BackgroundWorker is designed for this.  What do you mean by "cannot be background".  A background thread is the same as another thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet the way I understand it is that background = true or backgroundworker threads will not cause the application to wait before it closes. A user could close the App at any time, but I need all Thread processing to finish before it closes.

Comment: @Encryption: Well the process can always be terminated by the user anyway... and if the user has closed the UI, where would you want to execute the extra code after the thread had finished?

Comment: My need is that, I don't want the user to be able to close the UI and it cause my processes to end abruptly. That's why I didnt go with backgroundworker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass new anonymous method, which calls `GetAppUpdates()` and some other method, which notify you about getting updates completed:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { GetAppUpdates(); Completed(); }));
t.Start();
```

`Completed` method will be called after your `GetAppUpdates()` method will be executed:

```
private void Completed()
{
   if (InvokeRequired)
   {
      Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { Completed(); });
      return;
   }

   // update UI
}
```

**BTW** This will do the job, but I'd better go with BackgroundWorker - it is designed for such tasks, and it's RunWorkerCompleted event handler will run on UI thread, which is very handy.

Comment: Ahh interesting...so after calling Invoke for that Method I'm UI Safe again?

Comment: @Encryption exactly, thats why we have `InvokeRequired` property and `Invoke` method :)

Comment: Nice...that beats calling Invoke for each UI control

Comment: Works well. May not be the most popular way of coding multi-threaded app but I have a particular need in this situation that backgroundworker just wasn't fulfilling. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing this using `Task` instead of thread.  Since you're updating the UI in your completion, you need to make sure it runs in the UI thread.  This can be done via a *continuation*:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAppUpdates());
task.ContinueWith(t => UpdateUserInterface(),
                     TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Is that .Net 4.0 only? I'm stuckin 3.5

Comment: @Encryption yes, Tasks available on .Net 4.0

Comment: @Encryption You can use it in 3.5 if you install an older version of the Rx Extensions (which include a backport of the TPL)